# Function execution took 60012 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, axios, google-cloud-functions

Summary of problem : I want to trigger a POST request from my Firebase Cloud Function to my node.js backend currently running on my local computer. The function execution starts but the POST call never reaches the backend.

Development environment :

- Firebase Realtime DB : Blaze plan. New entry in DB triggers Cloud Function.
- Firebase Cloud Function : axios 0.19.2, firebase-admin 8.10.0, firebase-functions 3.6.1.
- Backend : node v12.14.1, http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000

Expected results : POST call from Firebase Cloud Function triggers a route in node.js backend to process the data received in POST call.

Actual result : POST call never reaches node.js backend currently running on local computer. Log in Firebase Cloud Functions console :

> Function execution took 60012 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

What have I tried so far ?

- POST call from POSTMAN reaches my backend without any problem.
- Replacing axios by request-promise-native to make the POST call.
- Replacing http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000 by http://localhost:3000.
- Using .then().catch() syntax of axios.
- Using async await syntax of axios with a try & catch structure.

Firebase Cloud Function code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const BACKEND_URL = 'http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000';

exports.triggerNotification = functions.database.ref('/sessions/{sessionID}/{message}')
  .onCreate(function(snapshot, context) {
    const createdContent = snapshot.val();
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
    if (!createdContent) {
      return;
    }
    return axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/notification/trigger`, { createdContent } ,config);
  });
```

Node.js Backend code :

```
router.post('/trigger', function (req, res) {
  console.log('req.body', req.body);
  res.status(200).send('Post request received');
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're using IP addresses and the backend is running on your local computer since you tried localhost and it's formatted like that in your code.  You say postman works, but are you trying that from outside your network?  My guess is that the connection is getting blocked.  Can you try a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that exposes a local server?  Also make sure to try that with https.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: I can't thank you enough. If you prefer, you can write the answer, I will upvote it and delete mine. Please let me know. I don't want to take credit for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using IP addresses and the backend is running on your local computer since you tried localhost and it's formatted like that in your code. You say postman works, but are you trying that from outside your network? My guess is that the connection is getting blocked. Can you try a service like ngrok that exposes a local server? Also make sure to try that with https